# Dados php desaparecem na página

Tags: php

Tenho um código em PHP e ao visualizar a página ele corta-me os dados de texto.

```php
echo '<div id="tabs-2">
<p><b>Ficha de Aptidão Médica:</b></p>

<p>Trabalhador (1) Validade:';
if ($exibe['MedicaValidade'] != '0000-00-00')
{
    if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) 
    {
        echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].'</span>';
        echo 'Anexo :<a href="MostrarMedica.php?id='. $exibe['id'].'">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a>';
    } else {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
        echo '<a href="MostrarMedica.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a></p>';
    }
}

'<p>Trabalhador (2) Validade:';
if ($exibe['MedicaValidade2'] != '0000-00-00')
{
    if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade2']) < time()) 
    {
        echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade2'].'</span>';
        echo '<a href="MostrarMedica2.php?id='. $exibe['id'].'">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a>';
    } else {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade2'];
        echo '<a href="MostrarMedica2.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a></p>';
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparece assim, desorganizado.

Eu quero colocar:

> Trabalhador (1) Validade: 2014-30-05 Anexo: VER
>   Trabalhador (2) Validade: 2014-30-05 Anexo: VER

E mostrar sempre mais caso a data seja diferente de `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe do seu arquivo está toda bagunçada. Vocês esqueceu vários `echo` e aspas sem fechar no decorrer do seu código! O seguinte código irá funcionar como desejado:

```
<?php

echo '<div id="tabs-2">';
echo '<p><b>Ficha de Aptidão Médica:</b></p>';

if ($exibe['MedicaValidade'] != '0000-00-00') {
    echo '<p>Trabalhador (1) Validade:';
    if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {
        echo '<span style="color:red">' . $exibe['MedicaValidade'] . '</span>';
        echo 'Anexo :<a href="MostrarMedica.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a>';
    } else {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
        echo '<a href="MostrarMedica.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a></p>';
    }
}

if ($exibe['MedicaValidade2'] != '0000-00-00') {
    echo '<p>Trabalhador (2) Validade:';
    if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade2']) < time()) {
        echo '<span style="color:red">' . $exibe['MedicaValidade2'] . '</span>';
        echo '<a href="MostrarMedica2.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a>';
    } else {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade2'];
        echo '<a href="MostrarMedica2.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Porém, para não ficar repetindo código, tente agrupar a saída do seu banco de dados usando [estruturas de repetição](http://feloliveira.com.br/blog/estruturas-de-repeticao-em-php-while-do-while-for-e-foreach/) :

```
<div id="tabs-2">
<p><b>Ficha de Aptidão Médica:</b></p>

<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($trabalhador); $i++) {
    if ($trabalhador[$i]['MedicaValidade'] != '0000-00-00') {
        echo '<p>Trabalhador ({$i]}) Validade:';
        if (strtotime($trabalhador[$i]['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {

            echo "<span style='color:red'>{$trabalhador[$i]['MedicaValidade']}</span>";
        } else {
            echo $trabalhador[$i]['MedicaValidade'];
        }
        echo "Anexo :<a href='MostrarMedica.php?id={$trabalhador[$i]['id']}'>&nbsp; Ver PDF</a>";
    }
}
?>

</div>
```

PS.: O código acima não irá funcionar direto na sua aplicação, mas repare a diferença na organização e diminuição na repetição de código.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Mas a uma coisa que não ficou a funcionar que é quando a validade é 0000-00-00 eu não quero que ele mostre nada

Comment: Basta mover para dentro do if

Comment: Esse php já não se usa...porque não fazes um php como deve ser ..com estrutura com funções e chamas pelo ajax  ;) e metes o que queres